# AddnewRow Property doesn't work in devexpress grid view

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I am trying to fetch my data to gridview in devexpress as you can see here:

```
 private void frmDocument_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gridControlDocument.DataSource = _documentRepository.Get().ToList();
        }
```

[image]

As you can see i put a button to add a new record :

```
 private void btnNewRecordDocument_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        gridViewDocument.AddNewRow();

    }
```

But it doesn't work ,and it doesn't add any record to gridview why ?as you can see in the picture the `append or +` button is disable in gridview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work if your datasource is a list.  You need to change it to a BindingList :

```
private void frmDocument_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridControlDocument.DataSource = 
       new BindingList<SomeClass>(_documentRepository.Get().ToList()) { AllowNew = true};
}
```

Comment: Yes i will do that .